# What happens when I add a "comment for the author" that's already there?

Tags: support, review-queues

When reviewing low-quality posts, I'm asked if I want to add a comment for the author:

[image: the prompt]

Of course, I'm not always the first reviewer, and sometimes the comment that I'd like to add is already there. What happens if I pick the option I want and hit the button? Does it add the comment even though it's already there, creating a duplicate? Does it just ignore my comment? Or does it work a bit like the flagging system, where more people picking the option somehow gives it more weight?

Comment: I believe picking the same comment upvotes the existing one. (Just like dupe votes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will upvote the existing one.

Comment: Wow, one of the shortest answers I ever gave on meta :D

Comment: ... I should just have answered instead of commented o.O

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes you should. Comments are not for 'trivial' answers, they are for clarifications/requests for more information. The place for 'trivial' answers is... well... in the answers!

Comment: Ah well, there's always a next time!

Comment: @Cerbrus I upvoted your comment anyway.